# Google Chrome opens window.open(someurl) just fine...but page/window with clicked link also opens someurl.com

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, onclick, window.open

As the title says "Google Chrome opens window.open(someurl) just fine...but page/window with clicked link also opens someurl.com.

When I click the "Click here" link with the onclick="shpop..." call attached, my pop up opens /facebook_login.php' correctly...BUT...at the same time, the original window opens /facebook_login.php too!

This happens in Chrome and IE, but FF is fine and doing just what i want..

I have this link:

```
<a href="/facebook_login.php" onclick="shpop('','','loginfb','');return false">Click here</a>
```

I know I could remove the href="/facebook_login.php" and replace with href="#" .. but I need the link to work if js is disabled.

I have this js code imported in my  tag:

```
function shpop(u,t,w,v)  
{
    var text = encodeURI(t);
    var uri = encodeURI(u);
    var h = document.location.href;
    h = encodeURI(h);
    var wwidth='600'; /*popup window width*/
    var wheight='300'; /*popup window height*/
    if(v=='' || undefined==v)v=document.domain; /*popup name/title */

   switch(w){
       case 'loginfb':
           var url = '/facebook_login.php';
           wwidth='980';
           wheight='600';
       break;
   }

    window.open(url,v,'width='+wwidth+',height='+wheight);
    return false
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is with returning false, and having false in the onclick?

This

```
onclick="shpop('','','loginfb','');return false"
```

Just needs to be

```
onclick="return shpop('','','loginfb','');"
```

If the onclick returns any error, the link will still open up. Do you see any errors in the JavaScript console? I wonder if the browsers are freaking out about any . in the window name from using document.domain. Try giving it a name.

```
onclick="return shpop('','','loginfb','foobar');"
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the latest [browser statistics](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp) - well last time it was measured anyway (2008) only 5% of users had Javascript disabled.  Nowadays it's likely to be less.  Consider that all browsers have it enabled by default.  Therefore it's generally only advanced users that for whatever reason choose to disable javascript, and will therefore understand that there's a good chance any website they visit won't work as expected - Facebook, Google, Amazon - everyone uses javascript these days.  It's perfectly acceptable to assume the user is using it, with one overall `<noscript>` version at the start of  your page for those users if you really really want to cover all your bases :)

Comment: As someone who browses with NoScript, I can't stand it when websites break basic functionality like links when Javascript is disabled. I don't mind fancy AJAX features not working, but simple content should just work.

Comment: brilliant, was hoping someone like you would reply.  Could you explain why you turn javascript off on all pages by default? I mean I understand some sites - eg gmail javascript version just about destroys my netbook, while their plain text version is fine, but in general it only serves to enhance. AJAX is no longer considered 'fancy' - most big sites use it now!

Comment: Often, new browser security exploits seem to use Javascript - not that JS itself is insecure, but usually it seems to be used to trigger a security flaw in other protocols. So by default I browse with JS disabled, and hopefully I will get a bit of extra protection in case someone finds a new exploit. For trusted sites I'll enable JS.

With JS disabled, I expect some things to fail - that's fine, I'll then decide whether to enabled it or not for that site. But basic HTML functionality (like links and forms) I expect to work regardless.

Comment: Seems fair enough.  I would also agree that links should still work - if it works in the lynx webbrowser it's a good test ;)  But I was more addressing his insistence of allowing for non-javascript users for everything: I just came across this:http://smorgasbork.com/component/content/article/84-a-study-of-internet-users-cookie-and-javascript-settings which indicates less than half a percent have it turned off now.

Comment: Another factor to consider is in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121108/how-many-people-disable-javascript question - someone points out you still want your site to work for non-standard access like screenreaders, search engines and mobile browsers - and - amusingly given the topic of discussion - non-standard browsers with potentially buggy javascript engines ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest solution:

```
<a href="/facebook_login.php" 
    target="FBpopup" 
    onclick="window.open('about:blank','FBpopup','width=980,height=600')">
    Click here
</a>
```

You don't need `return false` because you actually want the link to execute.

The trick is to use the ***same window name*** in both the window.open and in the link target.

window.open will create the popup, then your login page will run in that popup.

If popups are blocked or Javascript is disabled, your login page will run in a new tab.